# Neo4J Matching Nodes Based on Multiple Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I had another thread about this where someone suggested to do

```
MATCH (p:Person {person_id: '123'})
WHERE ANY(x IN $names WHERE
  EXISTS((p)-[:BELONGS]-(:Face)-[:CORRESPONDS]-(:Image)-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]-(:Dias {group_name: x})))
MATCH path=(p)-[:ASSOCIATED_WITH]-(:Person)
RETURN path
```

This does what I need it to, returns nodes that fit the criteria without returning the relationships, but now I need to include another param that is a list.

```
....(:Dias {group_name: x, second_name: y}))
```

I'm unsure of the syntax.. here's what I tried

```
WHERE ANY(x IN $names and y IN $names_2 WHERE..
```

this gives me a syntax error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ANY()` function can only iterate over a single list, it would be difficult to continue to use that for iteration over 2 lists (but still possible, if you create a single list with all possible `x/y` combinations) AND also be efficient (since each combination would be tested separately).

However, the new [existenial subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#existential-subqueries) synatx introduced in neo4j 4.0 will be very helpful for this use case (I assume the 2 lists are passed as the parameters `names1` and `names2`):

```
MATCH (p:Person {person_id: '123'})
WHERE EXISTS {
  MATCH (p)-[:BELONGS]-(:Face)-[:CORRESPONDS]-(:Image)-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]-(d:Dias)
  WHERE d.group_name IN $names1 AND d.second_name IN $names2
}
MATCH path=(p)-[:ASSOCIATED_WITH]-(:Person)
RETURN path
```

By the way, here are some more tips:

- If it is possible to specify the direction of each relationship in your query, that would help to speed up the query.
- If it is possible to remove any node labels from a (sub)query and still get the same results, that would also be faster. There is an exception, though: if the (sub)query has no variables that are already bound to a value, then you would normally want to specify the node label for the one node that would be used to kick off that (sub)query (you can do a PROFILE to see which node that would be).